# JAVA_HOME returns blank Linux Mint 18.3

Tags: java, java-8, linux-mint, java-home

After update of Linux I have an issue with JAVA_HOME directory. echo doesn't find directory for JAVA_HOME.

I have uninstalled java using:

> apt-get purge oracle-java8-installer

Then

> apt-get update

Then apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

After this I have checked if /etc/environment has correct JAVA_HOME directory and everything is correct but "echo $JAVA_HOME" still returns blank. I couldn't find solutions on google (even on stackoverflow). I am newbie, maybe I am doing something in wrong way.

How I can try to resolve this problem?

On the screen I have attached commands which I used to check correct directory.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/di7FG.png]

Comment: Have you tried it in a new terminal?

Comment: Each shell has it's own environment variables and changing files on the file system won't reload or change them.

Comment: And why should it not be blank? JAVA_HOME is just an environment variable, that is used by some tools of the Java ecosystem. But it isn't used by Java, and it isn't set when installing Java. So, if you don't create this environment variable, it won't exist. Why do you think you need it in the first place?

Comment: @ernest_k Yes, with no results. I also did reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux is case sensitive.  You are setting `JAVA_Home` but trying to use `JAVA_HOME`.

I suggest setting `JAVA_HOME` only.